# ILR - staying outside UK for one straight year

Tags: united-kingdom

I hold an ILR status in the UK. I intend to stay in Canada for one straight year so i could meet the requirements to retain my Canadian PR as well. Do you think my ILR status in the UK will be revoked?

Comment: Do you realize this is a public forum where other expats try to help as best as they can, not some official customer support contact point? “I look forward to your immediate reply on this matter.” is completely out of line…

Comment: Also - how can you be *permanently* resident in more than one place at a time?

Answer (score 3):

According to the [UKVI](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/period-that-individuals-may-be-outside-the-uk-without-losing-their-indefinite-leave-to-remain/period-that-individuals-are-allowed-to-be-outside-the-uk-without-losing-their-indefinite-leave-to-remain), it seems like leaves shorter than 2 years are allowed. The do I net I found does not explain how the time period is calculated. Presumably, leaving for 2 years, returning for a day, and leaving for another two years would not be allowed. It seems like leaving for 1 year might be allowed. That said, it seems weird to be a permanent resident in two countries. You might be better off applying for citizenship someplace.

Answer (score 2):

Your status likely won't be revoked. But you had better be ready to convince the Border Patrol agent that you are returning to permanently live in the UK, and especially that it was your primary residence the entire time anyway. There is a decent chance that they will notice that you are maintaining your Canadian PR as well. The most important thing to remember is that you should be honoring in spirit the conditions of that visa i.e. making the UK your primary home. This will be the deciding factor as to whether you ILR will be canceled or not.